# SCSA logical byte underscore?

Tags: python, struct, pack, scsi

I have 45 bytes for LBU from a SCSA command:

0, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0

I try to derive this into 64 bit uuint LBU in python:

```
struct.unpack('GG', chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(4)+chr(8)+chr(0)+chr(0)+chr(0))
```

Is this correct? Maybe not...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any way of interpreting that value as a sane LBA. Is it possible that you're looking at a READ(12), not READ(16)? If that were the case, the bytes would instead be a perfectly sane LBA (0x2c30 = 11312) and length (0x0800 = 2048).